# Sideways/vertical spanner label in gt tables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, gt

I have two dataframes that I want to turn into a single table using `gt`

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
a <- rnorm(21, mean = 112, sd =12)
colour <- rep(c("Blue", "Red", "Green"), 7)
data <- data.frame(colour, a)

data <- data %>% 
  group_by(colour) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(a), sd = sd(a), n = n()) %>%
ungroup() %>% 
  gt()


a <- rnorm(21, mean = 60, sd =12)
day <- rep(c("2", "4", "6"), 7)
data2 <- data.frame(day, a)

data2 <- data2 %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(a), sd = sd(a), n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  gt()
```

How do I stack the two dataframes on top of each other, and apply two sideways spanner labels of colour and day. Something similar to below where 2014, 2015 are my mean and sd columns, and China is colour, with blue, red green underneath, and India is day with the days stacked underneath.

OR (for curiosity/ideally).

Not have colour and day where China and India are, but instead have a sideways spanner. (i.e. vertical instead of horizontal). Horizontal isn't good for my real data as there is too many categories and would make it a really wide table.

[image]

Comment: This issue has been open for a while on GitHub https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give each a variable to identify what the group will be ("grp") and rename the color/day variable ("cat") and use `bind_rows` to combine them before using `gt`:

```
a <- rnorm(21, mean = 112, sd =12)
colour <- rep(c("Blue", "Red", "Green"), 7)

data <- data.frame(colour, a) %>% 
  group_by(colour) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(a), sd = sd(a), n = n()) %>%
  mutate(grp = "colour") %>% 
  rename(cat = colour)

b <- rnorm(21, mean = 60, sd =12)
day <- rep(c("2", "4", "6"), 7)

data2 <- data.frame(day, b) %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(a), sd = sd(a), n = n()) %>%
  mutate(grp = "day") %>% 
  rename(cat =  day)

bind_rows(data, data2) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  gt(rowname_col = "cat")
```

Also I don't think this is exactly what you are asking for on the second option, but there is a `row_group.as_column` option for `tab_options`:

```
bind_rows(data, data2) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  gt() %>%
  tab_options(row_group.as_column = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you looks great! As per the GitHub looks like the vertical spanner issue hasn't been resolved entirely, but this code is helpful regardless!